# I want to writing the matrix on the arrow from X to Y 3x3 type, from Z to Y 3x2 type ;

Tags: pdftex, tikz-cd, winedt

[image]

How can I program the above diagram? `

```
$$ \begin{tikzcd} k\oplus k^2 \arrow[r] & k\oplus k^2 & 0\oplus k \arrow[l] \end{tikzcd} $$
```

`

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code, and explain  what X, Y and Z are ?

Comment: X: k \ oplus k ^ 2 , Y: k \oplus k^2 , Z: 0 \oplus k

Comment: @tuce Can you put also a figure to undestand what do you want?

Comment: @sebastiano I added the diagram I wanted to do

Comment: @tuce Very good! Thus you have had several answers. Good work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two realizations; to be honest, I'd prefer the second one. For the first, I define a variant of `smallmatrix` with increased line spacing.

Note that `ampersand replacement` is needed as you want to use `&` for the matrices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\xsmallmatrix\smallmatrix
\let\endxsmallmatrix\endsmallmatrix
\patchcmd{\xsmallmatrix}{6\ex@}{12\ex@}{}{}
\newenvironment{bxsmallmatrix}
 {\left[\xsmallmatrix}
 {\endxsmallmatrix\right]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=huge]
k\oplus k^2
\arrow[r,"{\begin{bxsmallmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bxsmallmatrix}}"]
\&
k\oplus k^2
\&
0\oplus k \arrow[l,"{\begin{bxsmallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\\0&1\end{bxsmallmatrix}}"']
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=huge]
k\oplus k^2
\arrow[r,"{\begin{bsmallmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bsmallmatrix}}"]
\&
k\oplus k^2
\&
0\oplus k \arrow[l,"{\begin{bsmallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\\0&1\end{bsmallmatrix}}"']
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A simple code with `tikz-cd` and the `bsmallmatrix` environment from `mathtools`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
 \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.2cm, column sep=2cm, arrows=-stealth, ampersand replacement=\&]
  k\oplus k^2\rar{\begin{bsmallmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bsmallmatrix}} \& k\oplus k^2\& \lar[swap]{\begin{bsmallmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{bsmallmatrix}} 0\oplus k
   \end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit* :

To have control on the horizontal spacing in the matrices, you can use the `bmatrix` environment, and use the classical tools `\arraystretch` and `\arraycolsep`(defaults `1` and `5pt` respectively). For instance:

```
   \[ \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}\setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}
     \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.2cm, column sep=2cm, arrows=-stealth, ampersand replacement=\&]
      k\oplus k^2\rar{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}} \& k\oplus k^2\& \lar[swap]{\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}} 0\oplus k
       \end{tikzcd}
    \]
```

yields this diagram:

[image]

Comment: It would be very nice to improve the vertical spacing between the matrix elements. To my taste, they are very close each other.

Comment: It's the default in this environment, but I'll fix it in a moment.

Comment: @MarianG.: I've added a code  to have another spacing.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to use the basic tools of the tikz-machinery. In fact, the following code is only a very simple exercise and you can modify it further according to your notion.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {$k\oplus k^2$};
\node (B) at ($(A)+(3,0)$) {$k\oplus k^2$};
\node (C) at ($(B)+(3,0)$) {$0\oplus k$};
%
\draw[-stealth]
    (A) -- (B)
    node[midway,above,scale=.5]
        {$\begin{bmatrix}
            1& 0& 0\\
            0& 1& 0\\
            0& 0& 1
          \end{bmatrix}$};
\draw[-stealth]
    (C) -- (B)
    node[midway,above,scale=.5]
        {$\begin{bmatrix}
            0& 0\\
            0& 1\\
            0& 1
          \end{bmatrix}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @tuce Please, correct the first matrix in the code. I've assumed the unit matrix.

Comment: what should i do to make double arrow ? @Marian G.

Comment: @tuce To double the line, simply add the option `double` to the `\draw`-command, i.e., `\draw[-stealth,double]`. However, I'm not sure about your formulation "double arrow".