# I want to write matrices in diagram.help me

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I have drawn the diagram but I can not make the matrices

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
    k^2 &&\arrow[ll,shift left]
      \arrow[ll,shift right,swap]
    k
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See the answers to your [previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/441909/i-want-to-writing-the-matrix-on-the-arrow-from-x-to-y-3x3-type-from-z-to-y-3x2). Also, please post a full compilable code. Where are the matrices you want to add?

Comment: @tuce: you can add the `bmatrix` or `bsmallmatrix` environment as ar gument  of `\arrow`.